# Is it inevitable to compute the quadruople tensor in components? Why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, tensor-calculus, multipole-expansion

I was trying to determine the quadrupole tensor for a given charge distribution in one go from this equation:

$$\overleftrightarrow{D}=\int d^3r \varrho(\vec{r})\left(3\vec{r} \circ \vec{r}-r^2\hat{I} \right)$$

I am trying to understand why my findings were wrong. I found that the tensor is commonly calculated by components. Why is that so? Can't I just use this formula?

Just to clarify, here is what I put for $\rho$ for the charge distribution below:

$$\rho(\vec{r}) = Q\cdot \left(\delta^3\left(\vec{r}-\frac{3}{2}\vec{a}\right) 
+\delta^3\left(\vec{r}+\frac{3}{2}\vec{a}\right)
-\delta^3\left(\vec{r}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}\right) 
-\delta^3\left(\vec{r}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}\right)\right)$$
[image]

Comment: Please type your work out.

Comment: [Here's the notation we use.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to? 
$$\tag{1}\mathbf{D}=\int d^3r\,\rho(r)\begin{pmatrix}
3x^2-r^2 & 3yx & 3zx \\ 
3xy & 3y^2-r^2 & 3zy\\ 
3xz & 3yz & 3z^2-r^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Looks rather strange. Components
$$D_{ij}=\int d^3x \,\rho(x)(3x_ix_j-r^2\delta_{ij})$$
are much better.

Besides, you're going to calculate (1) component by component anyway. It's not like you can integrate a matrix in one fell swoop.

Comment: I see why it's better, but I'd like to understand why exactly my method is wrong. :)

Comment: How do you propose to do that integral without doing each component individually?

Comment: I thought I might just get rid of it because of the delta functions. Sorry if I am being really stupid here, long day..

Comment: @ari: Delta functions?

Comment: or distributions - I used them to describe $\rho$ (see image).

Comment: typed my work out now!

Comment: ah I see now. No integration of whole matrices. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need X and Y components, since everything is along the z axis.
Just get $[{\bf D}]=2\times2Q[(3/2)^2-(1/2)^2]{\bf{\hat z}{\hat z}}=8Q{\bf{\hat z}{\hat z}}.$

Comment: I don't quite understand your notation, but the correct solution is $D_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$ and, $D_{33}=8Qa^2$ with $D_{11}=D_{22}=-\frac{1}{2}D_{33}$ for anybody with the same problem.